# Количество добавляемого товара в корзину

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть кнопка добавляющая 1-н товар в корзину:

```
<%= button_to 'Добавить в корзину', line_items_path(item_id: @item) %>
```

line_items_controller:

```
def create

@cart = current_cart
item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_item(item)
```

Подскажите как реализовать возможность задания количества товара добавляемого в корзину и как потом в корзине это количество можно менять.

UPD: Пояснение: я имею в виду как связать с кнопкой текстовое поле в котором будет вводится количество товара?

Comment: я имею в виду как связать с кнопкой текстовое поле в котором будет вводится количество товара?

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем новое свойство quantity в модель LineItem

Далее

```
def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
  current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
  end
   current_item
 end
```

В файле миграции

```
def up
  # замена нескольких записей для одного и того же товара в корзине одной записью
  Cart.all.each do |cart|
  # подсчет количества каждого товара в корзине
  sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
  sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
  if quantity > 1
     # удаление отдельных записей
  cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all
  # замена одной записью
  cart.line_items.create(product_id: product_id, quantity: quantity)
  end
  end
 end
 end
```